# Assign a row a number from 1 to X then loop - In SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Say you have a table with an ID column and a few text columns, and you want to assign each one a number from 1 to 4. 
This number will loop around to 1 after it has reached 4 like so:

```
ID Num ...
 1   1 
 2   2
 3   3
 4   4
 5   1
 6   2
 7   3
 8   4
 9   1
 .   .
 .   .
 .   .
```

I've been trying to figure out this little puzzle for a while now. I've been trying to use `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`, but had no success so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
select 
   id,
   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by id) - 1) % 4 + 1 As nr 
from 
   tbl
```

Comment: Very clever Magnus! I've been scratching my head about this for a while now. This does it perfectly.